# Creating a map in java with 2 keys for index and key

Tags: java, arrays, maps, 2d

I have a problem solving this task. I have to create a map out of a 2d array with the name 'phoneBook'. 
This is my code so far:

```
Map<String, String> phoneBook2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i=0;i<phoneBook.length;i++){   
    phoneBook2.put("firstname",phoneBook[i][0]);
}
for (int i=0;i<phoneBook.length;i++){
    phoneBook2.put("surname",phoneBook[i][1]);
}
for (int i=0;i<phoneBook.length;i++){
    phoneBook2.put("phoneNumber",phoneBook[i][2]);
}
```

My idea was to insert the value of the 2d array into the map with the key firstname, surname and phoneNumber. I saw that only the last value got assigned to the key. Can I only assign one value to one key?

The second problem is that those assert codes have to work:

```
assert phoneBook2.get(0).get("firstname").equals(phoneBook[0][0]);
assert phoneBook2.get(0).get("surname").equals(phoneBook[0][1]);
assert phoneBook2.get(0).get("phoneNumber").equals(phoneBook[0][2]);
assert phoneBook2.size() == 100;
```

As you can see there two get functions are being called so I suppose I have to create two keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have many phone books in 2d array. And to save them you must have a Map array:

```
List<Map<String,String>> list = new List<>();
for (int i=0;i<phoneBook.length;i++){ 
    Map<String, String> phoneBook2 = new HashMap<String, String>();  
    phoneBook2.put("firstname",phoneBook[i][0]);
    phoneBook2.put("surname",phoneBook[i][1]);
    phoneBook2.put("phoneNumber",phoneBook[i][2]);
    list.add(phoneBook2);
}
```

Then you can:

```
list.get(0).get("firstname");
```